# Getting Error while importing Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to import a Maven project, but getting below error:
An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/PackageFragment.

I have tried creating a new workspace and also tried deleting .snap file at this location  \.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources (this file keeps getting created automatically). No other options are working, can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-installing eclipse and then try importing the project, this is how I have resolved this error.